# How can I protractor-cucumber and gulp-cucumber?

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I need use `Cucumberjs` to test for front-end (Angular2).

I want use `protractor-cucumber` and `gulp-cucumber` to run test on chrome(to debug), write test case with `cucumberjs` syntax, and handle browser by `protractor`.

How can I do it?
Please help me, thanks.

Comment: There are too many open ended questions in there.